# Run inline rails with jquery button click

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a button and when I click it I want it to run inline rails that changes the value of a variable. I was wondering if this was even possible. This is what I have so far. Thank you for the help.

```
</script>
  <%
    number = 0
  %>

$(button).click(function(){
    <%
       number = 1
    %>
});
<script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to update a server side variable, `number`, using client side code as you have written here. The javascript code running on the client has no way of interacting with the ruby code running on the server.

The client code gets state from the server, but any changes that happen on the client side that are not communicated to the server will not be known to the server.

It is possible to change the state of the server asynchronously from the client using ajax.

```
$(button).click(function() {
  $.get('/set_number_to_one');
});
```

This would make an ajax GET request to the server to the `set_number_to_one` route which could adjust the value of `number` to be 1.

Comment: Thank you for the information. That worked.